# add shrink to array values content

Tags: javascript, php

I am showing the 5 first elements in a list and then have a link to display the remaining values.

JS

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
            if (clickEvent.target.id == 'showMore') {
                linksList.classList.add('expanded');
             document.getElementById("showMore").style.display = 'none';
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

CSS

```
     #linksList li.more-vs {
     display: none;
    }
   #linksList.expanded li {
     display: list-item;
       }
    </style>
```

Php

```
<ul id="linksList">
  <?php
    foreach($specializations as $index => $ac){
        $class = '';
        if ($index > 4) {
            $class = 'class="more-vs"';
        }
        echo '<li '.$class.'><a class="quicksearchid" qs_id="'.$ac->spId.'" href="#">'.$ac->spName.'</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
  <li><a href="#" id="showMore" >More<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to add shrink(less) link, if I click on less link it go back to 5 items just like toggle.

Comment: I have created a demo but I have cleaned up some of your existing `javascript` and added in some extra things to your existing function [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/skotbtkn/) I hope this helps.

Comment: its working fine, add answer so that i will accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same anchor element and function to deal with both hide/show.

I have also cleaned up some of your existing source code, I couldn't see why the event listener `click` would be set for the whole document if you only want to take action if a specific anchor tag is clicked.

I have placed comments within the source code to explain each line.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //Set click event to showMore anchor
  document.getElementById('showMore').addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
    //Target unordered list - linksList
    var Mylist = document.getElementById('linksList');
    //Toggle linkLists class
    Mylist.classList.toggle('expanded');
    //Does linkList have class expanded?
    if (Mylist.classList[0] == 'expanded') {
      //Change anchor innerHTML to Less and fontawesome
      this.innerHTML = 'Less<i class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    } else {
      //Change anchor innerHTML to More and fontawesome
      this.innerHTML = 'More<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#linksList li.more-vs {
  display: none;
}

#linksList.expanded li {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul id="linksList">
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  <li class="more-vs"><a href="#">Five</a></li>
  <li class="more-vs"><a href="#">Six</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="showMore">More<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps, happy coding!